# creating and querying local database with javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, sql, web

I am new to Javascript, HTML and the lot. I am making a simple web page that queries a database, everything is local as I am just exploring. I am having a lot of problems with making a database, nothing I use seems to work I've tried MongoDB, MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite. I am really just looking for something like pythons SQLite3 where I can simply create and query and should work in the browser.

Any tips on how this can be done?

I want to for example run a tryLogin(username, password) function on an html button onclick event. It queries the database and logs in.

Comment: TLDR you need a server side language to talk to the database. So you can use Node if you want to use js or php (if you are using a webserver). In case of php you can leverage AJAX to connect from your html page to the php backend

Comment: I think you can use the `sqlite3` module available in npm in the browser. I also recommend this package: https://sql.js.org/

Comment: @LelioFaieta You are off-topic. 1) This is totally possible and 2) the author is not using PHP.

Comment: You could give [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) a try. It's packed by default in all modern browsers. Although quite different from SQL syntax...

Comment: @Almaju OP is not using node either so npm is not in scope too. Direct connection from plain JS in an HTML page (OP's architecture) is not possible.

Comment: You can use npm in plain JS with Parcel / webpack etc. Direct connection to a local database is possible, they can use indexedDB, localStorage...